# Php code to parse table from aspx page to MySQL db

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I need to parse an HTML table into a mysqldb 
I searched through the website and I saw some codes how to do it through DOMdocument,
My problem is that since its a dynamic table look like the php only get the HTML source code (the same you get when you right click on webpage and press show source) but the acttual HTML code which rended when the page appear on a browser doesn't load into the Domdocument variable, 
Samples and reference will be appreciated 
Chaim

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Do you need to get the "dynamic generated table" only once ?

Comment: no i want acctualy to create a loop which get the new rows into db, insude the db i have a uniqe index which will prevent old rows to insert to the table again

Comment: If i understanding you right.. You need create simple page format, and parse to MySQL db in PHP script.. So.. you can use with XML/JSON and parse it really simple.. (I recommend to JSON ofc). Good luck.